# Linked list in a GTK3 key-release-event callback resulting in a free error

Tags: c, linked-list, gtk3

I'm trying to use a linked list as a data holder in a GTK3 `key-release-event` callback.
The constructor goes like this

```
   information *new_information ()
       {
          information *new;
          new = malloc (sizeof (new));
          new->name = malloc (sizeof (new->name));
          new->value = malloc (sizeof (new->value));
          new->prev = NULL;
          new->next = NULL;
          return (new);
        }
```

Every time I call it from the `key-release-event` callback function, the app crashes with a `free` error.
If I call it from outside the callback, everything goes smoothly. Also, even if I call it from the callback, if I don't set the `next` field, it doesn't trigger any error.

I've tried using `GList` and put my `struct` without any `next` or `prev` fields but it doesn't initialize the `struct`.

Comment: At least this statement new = malloc (sizeof (new)); is wrong. It seems you mean new = malloc (sizeof (*new)); The same problem can exist in these statements new->name = malloc (sizeof (new->name)); and new->value = malloc (sizeof (new->value));